# Determinant of a matrix of the form $M = I + \sum_{j=1}^m x_j x_j^\intercal$

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, determinant

This [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3083652/determinant-of-a-matrix-of-the-form-m-i-xxt) explains how to calculate $\det(I + x x^\intercal)$ where $x$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^d$, showing that $\det(I + x x^\intercal) = 1 + \|x \|^2. $

Now, if $x_1, ..., x_m$ are $m$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d,$ do we have $\det( I + \sum_{j=1}^m x_j x_j^\intercal ) = 1 + \sum_{j=1}^m \| x_j\|^2$ ?

Comment: Nope, but we have the [generalized matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma#Generalization) which equates the determinant of the $d \times d$ matrix to a $m \times m$ one: $\det(I_d + \sum_{j}x_jx_j^T) = \det(I_m + M)$  where $(M)_{ij} = x_i^T x_j$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim does not hold. Just consider
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$

In this case, $\det (I + x_1 x^T_1 + x_2 x^T_2) = 4$ but $1+\|x_1\|^2 +\|x_2\|^2 =3$.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right indeed: with $m=d$ and $x_j = e_j$, this would yield $2^m = m + 1$, which is true iff $m = 1$. Beautiful, thanks!